# C# Serial Port Sending Un-receivable data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm using .Net Framework 4 on Windows 8, and am having a very strange serial port problem.

I can receive data through a serial port, but when I send data from the same serial port, it does not get received by a very standard terminal emulator (H.  I see the TX LED light up from the transmitting port, and the RX LED light up from the receiving port, but it still does not show any received text.

For what reason would the receiving port not get/interpret/whatever the stream?

I am trying to send the string: "0300"
As a 4 byte byte array: 30-33-30-30

using the following line of code:

```
comm.Write(arrayToSend, 0, arrayToSend.Length);
```

Here's a photo of the COM Port configuration in debug:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any helpful insights :D

Thanks,
- Matt

Comment: Could be an electrical problem, you need a null-modem cable.  Or the program you use is paying attention to the hardware handshake lines, like it should.  Which is classically overlooked, too many programmers pick Handshake.None.  You will then have to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true yourself.

Comment: HAHA! I think you might be right. I was using some funky home-made connector that had worked before.  The cable I am now using uses ONLY TX, RX, and GND, and seems to be working.  I think the connector I was using before was holding a control line in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

```
comm.Flush();
```

your data.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm pretty sure what Hans Passant suggested fixed my problem :)